# Which part of the Vedas do Nyaya accept as authority?

Tags: vedas, upanishads, nyaya

What part of the Vedas do nyaya accept?

Comment: Advaita vedanta does not reject samhita. They accept samhita as karma kanda. Karma kanda is that portion of vedas dealing with rituals, sacrifices and their results.

Comment: @zero But they don't pratice it. You can see Mundaka Upanishad 1.2.9-10

Comment: The intention of that bhAshya is only to criticize those who perform karma with being solely guided by desire. It's not an unqualified denigration of karma. Check Isa upanishad bhAshya 1.2.

Comment: Just because they do not practice it doesnt mean they reject.